# Checking if a function was called while being called multiple times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing a game in C# with Unity and I designed some Quizzes for the Player.

It has a Manager-Script which is called from a trigger. I made 5 NPC-Characters who are triggering the Quizzes if the Player is nearby, but they are using the same trigger and manager-script. I would like to make a method which checks, if one Quiz was already answered correctly, while not blocking the Quizzes from other NPCs. I tried with a bool, but then I could answer the Quiz from NPC1, but the Quiz from NPC2 was already "marked" as answered correctly as well.

This is my Manager-Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using Ink.Runtime;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using Unity.Netcode;
using Unity.Netcode.Transports.UTP;

public class NPCQuizManager : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Dialog UI")]
[SerializeField] private GameObject dialogPanel;
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI dialogText;

[Header("Choices UI")]
[SerializeField] private GameObject[] choices;
private TextMeshProUGUI[] choiceTexts;
private Story currentStory;
public bool dialogIsActive{get; private set;}

private static NPCQuizManager instance;
private int rightChoice;


HealthManager hpLoss;
public GameObject player;

private void Awake(){

    if(instance != null){

        Debug.LogWarning("Es gibt mehrere Dialog Manager in der Scene!");
    }

        instance = this;
}

public static NPCQuizManager GetInstance(){

    if(instance == null){

        instance = new NPCQuizManager();
    }

    return instance;
}

private void Start(){

    dialogIsActive = false;
    dialogPanel.SetActive(false);

    choiceTexts = new TextMeshProUGUI[choices.Length];
    int index = 0;
    foreach(GameObject choice in choices){

        choiceTexts[index] = choice.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        index++;
    }
}

private void Update(){

    if(dialogIsActive){

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){

            ContinueStory();
        }
    }
}

public void StartDialog(TextAsset inkJSON, int correctChoice){

    rightChoice = correctChoice;
    currentStory = new Story(inkJSON.text);
    dialogIsActive = !dialogIsActive;
    dialogPanel.SetActive(dialogIsActive);
    ContinueStory();
}

public void ExitDialogeMode(){

    dialogIsActive = false;
    dialogPanel.SetActive(false);
    dialogText.text = "";
}

private void ContinueStory(){

    if(currentStory.canContinue){

        // Setze DialogText auf den nächsten Knoten
        dialogText.text = currentStory.Continue();
        // Zeige die Choices an
        DisplayChoices();
    }

    else{

        //ExitDialogeMode();
    }
}

private void DisplayChoices(){

    List<Choice> currentChoices = currentStory.currentChoices;

    //Check if there are more choices than UI elements
    if(currentChoices.Count > choices.Length){

        Debug.LogWarning("Es gibt mehr Choices als UI Elemente! Es werden nur: " + currentChoices.Count + " angezeigt!");
    }

    int index = 0;

    //Display all choices
    foreach(Choice choice in currentChoices){

        choices[index].SetActive(true);
        choiceTexts[index].text = choice.text;
        index++;
    }

    // Hide all unused choices
    for(int i = index; i < choices.Length; i++){

        choices[i].SetActive(false);
    }

    StartCoroutine(SelectFirstChoice());
}

private IEnumerator SelectFirstChoice(){
    //Das Eventsystem muss auf null gesetzt werden, damit es nicht mehr auf das letzte UI Element zeigt
    EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(choices[0].gameObject);
}

public void chooseChoice(int choiceIndex){

    currentStory.ChooseChoiceIndex(choiceIndex);

    if(choiceIndex == rightChoice){

        AddECTS();
    }

    else{

        looseHP();
    }

    ContinueStory();
}


public void AddECTS(){

    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    player.GetComponent<ECTSCounter>().erhoeheWert(5);
}

public void looseHP(){
    hpLoss = GameObject.Find("Healthbar").GetComponent<HealthManager>();
    hpLoss.TakeDamage(2);
}


}
```

I would appreciate and help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bit flag or bool array to save the answered question

```csharp
private bool[] answered = new bool[numberOfQuestions];

private bool AlreadyAnswered(int questionIndex){
  return answered[questionIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of marking a quiz answered I'd create a dictionary of players as heys and quizzes ids as values that stores who has taken part in which quiz:

```
private static Dictionary<GameObject, int> _quizzesParticipationTracing = new Dictionary<GameObject, int>();
// I see that your 'player' is of type GameObject, 
// but you can use any other unique reference to the player, 
// e.g. the UID, if available.
```

**EDIT:** After a sharp remark of @derHugo I realised that a dictionary cannot have multiple same keys holding different values. You can use the following code:

```
private static Dictionary<GameObject, HashSet<int>> _quizzesParticipationTracing = new Dictionary<GameObject, HashSet<int>>();
```

**End of edit.**

Then, each time a player appears near the quiz, you check whether the respective key exist in the dictionary already and which quizzes they participated in. And then you either display an available quiz or inform them that there aren't any quizzes available.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Maybe then rather a `Dictionary<GameObject, HashSet<int>` ? As I understand a player can participate in multiple quizzes

Comment: Of course, you're right. Don't know why I thought a dictionary can have multiple keys holding the values. I'll correct the example code.

Comment: Thanl you for your response. I haven't used Dicts before, how would i use that? Is the int the number of questions or the question index?

Comment: From MSDN: The `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` generic class provides a mapping from a set of keys to a set of values. Each addition to the dictionary consists of a value and its associated key. Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class is implemented as a hash table. As the name implies, you use it to store key-value pairs. In my answer the `int` is the question index - for each player you store a list (`HashSet`) of the question indices, which this particular player already answered.